# Implementation of dynamic_cast 

Tags: c++

The following code produces this output:

```
1 is a null pointer
2 is not a null pointer
```

**Code**

```
class base {};
class derived1: public base {};
class derived2: public base {};

int main() {
    base *baseptr[1];
    baseptr[0] = new derived2;
    derived1 *derptr = new derived1;
    derived1 *derivedptr1 = dynamic_cast<derived1*>(baseptr[0]);
    derived1 *derivedptr2 = dynamic_cast<derived1*>(derptr);
    cout<<((derivedptr1==0)?"1 is null pointer":"1 is not a null pointer") << endl;
    cout<<((derivedptr2==0)?"2 is null pointer":"2 is not a null pointer") << endl;
}
```

Why is derivedptr2 only initialised and derivedptr1 is not? As both have a valid right hand side value. Does this have something to do with dynamic cast and the fact that in second case I am casting a derived1* to a derived1*?

Comment: Please first explain what you find confusing or strange about the output.

Comment: Why did you include `static_cast` in the caption, when the actual question does not even mention `static_cast`?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your code is not compilable. In order to use `dynamic_cast` for anything else than upcasts you need a polymorphic type as the pointer operand. You are using it for [an attempted] cross-cast and your types are not polymorphic.

Secondly, if you make your classes polymorphic (so that the code compiles), then the behavior you report is really the expected behavior. The `derivedptr1` pointer should indeed be null since `derived2` object is not a `derived1` object (and the objects in question are not parts of any common superobject). The cross-cast fails, and the `dynamic_cast` therefore evaluates to a null pointer. Did you expect anything else?

In the second case (for `derivedptr2`) you have an "identity" cast of `derived1 *` to `derived1 *`. The type is the same, so this cast is essentially a no-op. It just evaluates to the original value.

Answer (score 1):

***dynamic_cast*** is used to check the validity of the downcast.
It returns a valid pointer if the pointer actually points to a type being casted to or a class derived from the class being pointed to.

`baseptr[0]` points to the type `derived2`.

With

```
dynamic_cast<derived1*>(baseptr[0]);
```

You are trying to check if `basepte[0]` actually points to `derived1` or a class derived from it. Obviously, its neither so it returns a `0`.

Similary, `derptr` is pointing to a type `derived1`.

With

```
dynamic_cast<derived1*>(derptr);
```

You are trying to check if `derptr` points to `derived1`, which is correct, hence it returns a valid pointer type, resulting in prints to Not null.

***A Caveat:***  As @AndreyT rightly pointed out `dynamic_cast` only works for `Polymorphic` classes!